# Turn off Skype 8.11 chat notification sounds

Tags: audio, notifications, high-sierra, skype

I upgraded to Skype 8.11 from 7.x and found that I am now getting audio notifications when I receive a chat message. In the previous version of Skype you had fine-grained control over the notification sounds and I had almost all of them disabled. In this version of Skype that option appears to have been removed.

In my application settings I only have 'Chat notifications' enabled; 'In-app notifications', and 'In-app sounds' and turned off.

[image: Skype application settings]

I have also turned off 'Play sounds for notifications' in Mac Notification settings:

[image: Mac Notification settings]

I am running macOS High Sierra (10.13.1).

How can I disable these sounds?

Comment: I'm afraid that crap just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to Skype version 8.29.0.50

fixes that problem.